# Problem with XMLhttpRequest returning empty response

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to build a new functionality in my website which requires me to retrieve a single value from the database i got on my web server.
To do this i use a php script server side which uses msqli to retrieve the data from the database. Client side i use Ajax and XMLhttpRequest to call the php script. Everything works fine and i dont have any errors except that my xml always has an empty response, which makes me think there is a problem with my php script. Could you guys help? ill include some code below.

[screenshot of my xmlhttprequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5MLU.png)

[screenshot of my network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBaKh.png)

this is my php script

```php
<?php


$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'nicolas', 'Password', 'RandomNumberHouse');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "error";
} 

$HouseID = 6;

$sql = "SELECT RandomVar FROM RandomVarHouse WHERE HouseID = $HouseID";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$var = $row[2];
echo $var;
$conn-> close();

?>
```

this is my js script

```
function getRandomVar(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../inc/VarCommunication.php?");
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var result = this.responseText;
            updateBackgroundColor(result);
        };
      }
}   


function updateBackgroundColor(number){
    if( number < 100){
        document.getElementById('mainBody').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the Network tab in your browser developer tools tell you about the HTTP response?

Comment: i only get the 200 status

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are there any error messages in the console or terminal you could add to your question?

Comment: Well thats the weird part, i dont have any errors whatsoever, i think the problem must be the output of my php script but i cant find any errors with it

Comment: Should i add a screenshot of the network tab and the contents of the xmlhttprequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you miss place semicolon in xmlhttp request. please try below code and verify result

  <script>
        function getRandomVar()
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","demo1.php");
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
                {
                    var result = this.responseText;
                    alert(result);
                    //updateBackgroundColor(result);
                }
              };
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Oh wow yes that was it, thank you for your help! stupid of me to not have seen that